# How to generate an apk without package one specific native library it depends on ？

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

As the title says. I'm trying to compile an apk without package one specific native library it depends on. May I ask how I can achieve that with android studio? Thanks in advance..

Comment: No, you cannot remove dependent libs.

Comment: Nope, you cannot... you can remove the use of the libraries & then remove its Dependencies